# Why do we need to register the I.P. and hostname of any zookeeper quorom in the clients /etc/hosts file to connect to HBase?

Tags: hbase

Why do I need to register the I.P. and hostname of any zookeeper quorom in the clients /etc/hosts file to connect to HBase ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't. HBase does require both forward and reverse name lookups for proper connectivity. However, this can be achieved via DNS and does not require `/etc/hosts` entries.